# Meaning of "yesterday's papers"

Tags: idioms, phrase-requests

What does this phrase mean? It should be an idiom and I can't find it.

Comment: I think Wayfaring Stranger has the right answer but to be sure, you can include the source of the phrase because sometimes the context can help the user community help you determine the correct answer.

Comment: People voting to close this as general reference: did you even *try* to look this up in a dictionary? Hint: you won't find it. Searching online is even worse, because the song drowns out any stray mentions of the phrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "papers" in the phrase refers to newspapers: periodicals printed on cheap paper that are, in many ways, out-of-date the minute they come off the presses. By the next day, the only thing a newspaper is good for is to wrap things, line things, or wipe things. Thus, "yesterday's papers" are things that are no longer useful for their original purpose, and any re-use you might get out of them will be low-value and low-status.

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday's papers are often today's bird cage liners, or fried fish wraps. You've not given much context, but the phrase often refers to something that is past use for its original purpose.

Comment: Or a song by The Rolling Stones

Comment: well, I don´t have a context, because I´m just trying to study for an exam :-). So does it mean something like "yesterday it was bad and today it is even worse?" thank you